# Requiring login to access my Wordpress site

Tags: php, authentication, conditional-statements

I have a Wordpress site and I want to be locked to the public, as in redirects to login, unless you're registering. So right now the code I'm using is:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

} else {
 $coolio=curPageURL();
 if (strpos($coolio,'register.php') !== false) {
 break;
 }
 else{
  echo "<script>window.location = 'http://example.com/wp-login.php'</script>";
  break;
 }
 if (strpos($coolio,'login.php') !== false) {
 break;
 }
 else{
  echo "<script>window.location = 'http://example.com/wp-login.php'</script>";
  break;
 }
}
?>
```

Seems like it should work, but it creates an infinite loop on any page I go to. Does anybody know why?

Note: `curPageUrl` just returns current page url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted has some significant security issues:

- A user can simply disable Javascript to prevent being redirected.
- A user can simply add `?register.php` to the URL to avoid triggering the redirect code.

Instead, use a server-side session variable check. If a 'logged in' flag is not set within the session, then you redirect to the login page.

This has 2 massive advantages:

1. the logged in state is kept somewhere where the user can't do anything to manipulate it, EXCEPT by logging in
2. If a malicious user just trashes the session cookie, they'll just get a new blank session and be considered "not logged in", and just get redirected again anyways.

Comment: Hmm. *In other words, this code is hopelessly crappily bad.* C'mon, tell us how you **really** feel.

Comment: @AdamMagyar - Message: Don't half-ass it, or Marc B will get your backend/better half. `:)`

Comment: Wow dude thanks for the prompt response. I'm not really doing this for anything that is security intensive, but I certainly see the value of just... not using shitty code. So in theory, I should be like if user is logged in, set variable to 1, if else  then 0?

Comment: yeah. basically in your actual login code, you do whatever equivalent of `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true` makes sense for your code, and check that on all of your protected pages. if that value doesn't exist, or isn't true, then redirect to login.

Comment: Awesome man, I'll get right to it. Infinitely appreciate your charity, lol.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use JavaScript for the redirect, do it with php.

Second do this logic instead:

```
if(!($_SESSION["loggedin"]== 1))
{
    if(!(stripos($url,'register.php')))
    {
        header('Location: http://example.com/wp-login.php', true, 302);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: `stropos()`, eh?  That's a new one.  Or maybe you meant `stripos()` :P

Comment: I typed it after midnight on a iPhone...  The code is simple, so I didn't worry that anyone could have much trouble implementing.